# Migrate SQL Server database to Azure along with database email and jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, sql-server-agent, database-mail

I am new to SQL Azure, we have taken the subscription of Azure SQL elastic pool.
I have two databases in my local SQL Server and it has a stored procedure which internally is calling `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` and I have scheduled these stored procedures to run in a job (`SQL Server Agent -> Scheduler`).

I want to move these two databases along with DB-mail accounts and SQL Server jobs to Azure. I am finding difficulties as in my subscription I am not able to see msdb, SQL Server Agent and database email. We want to go with only SQL Azure as service, no need your support on these.

I tried to deploy the database and getting the error message:

> Error
>   SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[AMPLoanAgingEMail]:
>   Procedure: [dbo].[AMPLoanAgingEMail] has an unresolved reference to object [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail].[@profile_name]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.

The expected result is I want to move those scheduled jobs and stored procedures to my Azure.

Comment: @LeonYue it's an unfortunate fact that posters often ask questions then never respond to your detailed answers.

Comment: As already stated in the answer, this is not supported by Azure SQL. It _is_ supported by Azure SQL _Managed Instance_ so you may want to look into that. Not sure about the email procs though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL database doesn't support `msdb` database. We can not migrate msdb to Azure or do anything with it in Azure SQL database.

[image]

For more details,  please see: [msdb database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/msdb-database?view=sql-server-2017).

[SQL server agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017) is only supported Azure SQL Managed Instance only.
 [image]

[Database email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-2017) also is not supported in Azure SQL Database.
[image]

This why you can not be able to see msdb , SQL server agent and database email.

Your stored procedure `[dbo].[AMPLoanAgingEMail]` could not call the `[msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]` in msdb. The error message also mentioned that.

For now, there isn't  a solution for msdb in Azrue SQL Database.

Before migrate your database to Azure SQL database, you can use [Data Migration Assistant(DMA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-2017) to help you assess your database.

Hope this helps.